# Possible solution for bitbucket pipeline docker-run limitation

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

My integration tests are highly dependent of a elastic search, given that to build my integration tests on bitbucket pipeline I would have to execute the docker-run command to be able to spin up my elastic-search instance during my integration tests.

But as probably some of you know, there's a limitation on the bitbucket pipeline

> See the Docker command line reference for information on how to use
>   these commands. Other commands, such as **docker run, are currently
>   forbidden for security reasons on our shared build infrastructure**.

So given that I don't know how can I spin-up my escluster with all configurations that I need inside, painless scripts, mappings, ports exposed to be available for my integrations tests.

Does someone have any idea how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I managed to get it working, I was struggling to run elastic search, due this error https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/111

This was fixed by applying the config `discovery-type: single-node`. Since I'm using this for integration tests I don't need to run ES in production mode. The thing is bitbucket-pipeline was not showing error logs for this error, so I was completely blind and I had to try many things till find out. Since I can't build and run my own image on pipelines, I uploaded an image with my own configuration (including single-node config) and scripts and to docker hub.

This is how my yaml looked like in the end:

```
image: maven:3.3.9
    pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
            caches:
              - maven
            script:
              - docker version
              - mvn clean package verify -Dmaven.docker.plugin.skip=true -s settings.xml
            services:
              - elasticsearch

    definitions:
      services:
        elasticsearch:
          image: elastic-search-bitbucket-pipeline
    options:
      docker: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define your elastic-search image as a service as described there:
[Use services and databases in Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-services-and-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-874786688.html)

Comment: is exactly what I'm trying right now, I don't see other option.

Comment: This is currently problematic when trying to run elasticsearch in development mode, since [bitbucket pipelines does not support variable names with periods](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Using-elasticsearch-docker-image-as-service-requires-periods-in/qaq-p/652493).

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for a more elaborate solution, I have created a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.0.1
COPY --chown=elasticsearch:elasticsearch elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
```

In the same folder I have also created a custom config `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
```

I then added the custom image to Docker Hub, for more info how to do that, look here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/

You can now use the custom image in your Pipelines service configuration and use it to run your tests.

You could also supply some more configuration inside your `elasticsearch.yml`
Enable CORS:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

Set discovery type:

```
discovery.type: single-node
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/xiting/elasticsearch-bitbucket-pipeline

Add service to your pipeline as below:

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &run-tests
        name: Run tests
        script:
          - sleep 30 # Waiting elasticsearch. In your real pipeline you can not use it.
          - curl -XGET localhost:9250/_cat/health
        services:
          - elasticsearch
  services:
    elasticsearch:
      image: xiting/elasticsearch-bitbucket-pipeline
      variables:
        ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
    docker:
      memory: 2048

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *run-tests
```